# SyntaxError: Invalid Character In Identifier: Line 12

Tags: python, sqlite, syntax

I am trying to make a dropdown menu and connect it to a database but I am getting the above error. It says the error is occurring on line 12. This code works on my friend's IDE but not on mine, I am using the PyCharm IDE. I have also tried using the "reformat code" function on my IDE. Following is the exact error:

```
File "/Users/hetparikh/PycharmProjects/BudCalculator/test.py", line 12
        'Food',
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

The code is

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3 as sq
import datetime

# Connect to SQLite
con = sq.connect('spent.db')

root = Tk()

# Options in dropdown menu
options = [
    'Food',
    'Transportation',
    'Entertainment',
    'Misc'
]

clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set('Expense')
drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *options, )
drop.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20)

def SaveExpenseType():
        c = con.cursor()

    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CAR (sql_date VARCHAR(20), sql_clicked VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)')
    today = str(datetime.date.today())
    today = today[8:] + '-' + today[5:7] + '-' + today[:4]
    c.execute('INSERT INTO CAR (sql_date, sql_clicked) VALUES (?, ?)', (today, clicked.get()))
    con.commit()

def query():
        conn = sq.connect('spent.db')

    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM car")
    records = c.fetchall()
    print(records)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

query_btn = Button(root, text="Show Records", command=query)
query_btn.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=137)

carB = Button(root, text="Enter", command=SaveExpenseType)
carB.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the _exact_ error message along with its stack trace into your question. And what version of Python are you using? Is your friend using the same version?

Comment: After fixing indent errors with your `c = con.cursor()` statements, this program loaded okay - no syntax errors. Its possible there is a non-ascii character in there that is decoded differently on different machines. Can you post the surrounding few lines as bytes objects `open("test.py", "rb").readlines()[10:14]` ?

Answer (score -1):

Try using double quotes to store options' values.

Comment: Single and double quotes are both okay. After fixing a few unrelated indent errors the code loaded for me without a syntax error.

Comment: @HetParikh - in`def SaveExpenseType():` the first line is indented 8 spaces, yet the following are 4 spaces. Sticking with 4 spaces (no tabs!) is the most accepted style.